# How to append the updated value every time?

Tags: loops, dictionary, append, store

I am using loops to append a new value, but in the result, it adds the updated value several times.
Here are my codes:

```
TWqs=[]
d=3  
for d in range(d):
    tmpp=tmp[(tmp['date'] == dates[d])]
    qs=tmpp.qs
    time=tmpp.time

    if tmpp is not []: 
        TWqspread=np.nansum(qs*time)/sum(time)
    else:
        TWqspread=0

    TWqs.append(TWqspread)
```

I want the result looks like:

```
TWqs=[2.8, 3.1, 2.9]
```

However, what I got is:

```
TWqs=[2.9, 2.9, 2.9]
```

How can I store the variable TWqs?
Thank you in advance!